# SQLAlchemy set default nullable=False

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy for Flask to create some models. The problem is, nearly all my columns need `nullable=False`, so I'm looking for a way to set this option as default when creating a column. Surely I could add them manually (as a Vim exercise), but I just don't feel like it today. For a reference, this is how my setup (`models.py`) looks like:

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

class User(db.Model):
     id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
     username = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
```

and many more. Is there a simple way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Default is `nullable=True`, I checked.

Comment: Just because this has gone back and forth, I checked the source.  The default is nullable=True unless the column is used as a primary key column, in that case the default is nullable=False

Comment: Link to docs supporting @prok statement above: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html?highlight=nullable#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.nullable

Answer (score 38, accepted):

just create a wrapper that sets it

```
def NullColumn(*args, **kwargs):
    kwargs["nullable"] = kwargs.get("nullable", True)
    return db.Column(*args, **kwargs)

...
username = NullColumn(db.String(80))
```

using `functools.partial` as recommended in the comments

```
from functools import partial
NullColumn = partial(Column, nullable=True)
```

Comment: Use functools.partial instead.

Comment: @PedroWerneck I dont disagree ... but just wanted to keep it simple for now :P  (although now that I added it ... thats pretty dang simple)

Comment: `functools.partial` messes up type inference in Python 3.6+. You'd need `from typing import Type; NullColumn : Type[Column] = partial(Column, nullable=True)` for lint and/or autocomplete to continue working, or just use the simple version.

Answer (score 6):

As [`Column`](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/585aa7d7575dfb9a90a00bbd00c68da9e2cb31d7/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py#L1133) is a class, subclassing might be a lot more extensible depending on your use case.

```
from sqlalchemy import Column as Col
    
class Column(Col):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('nullable', False)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Also note that the accepted answer sets the `nullable` to `True` if not set. The correct is `False`.

Comment: You make a fair point!

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer creates a wrapper for a `nullable = True` column called `NullColumn`, which is already what `Column` does by default. The question asks to set `nullable = False` (not `True`) as the default when creating a column.

```
from sqlalchemy import Column as Col

def Column(*args, **kwargs):
    kwargs.setdefault('nullable', False)
    return Col(*args, **kwargs)
```

This function returns a `Column` with `nullable = False` by default, which can also be overwritten with `nullable = True` if needed (unlike the `functools.partial` solution).

Answer (score 1):

Using the [typing support](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/changelog/whatsnew_20.html#new-typing-support-in-core-and-orm-stubs-extensions-no-longer-used) added in SQLAlchemy 2.0, non-nullability can be enforced [by not declaring the column's type as optional](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/changelog/whatsnew_20.html#step-four-remove-orm-mapped-column-directives-where-no-longer-needed).

In the example below, `name` may not be null, but `title` may be null, due to their type declarations.

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import orm
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped, mapped_column


class Base(orm.DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 't29522557'

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str]
    title: Mapped[str | None]


def dump(sql, *multiparams, **params):
    print(sql.compile(dialect=engine.dialect))


engine = sa.create_mock_engine('sqlite://', dump)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Output:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t29522557 (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
        name VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
        title VARCHAR, 
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Comment: That's nice to know before converting all your models to SQLA 2.0.